Overdetermined linear system of equations and coming up with the minimal solution
I have been thinking about the following problem. I have an overdetermined linear system of equations $Ax = b$.  The matrix $A$ has full rank.  All equations in the system have a specific form: either $x_i = b_k$ or $x_i - x_j = b_k$ where $k$ denotes the $k$-th equation.  In other words, for each row $i$ of the matrix $A$, there are two possibilities, either (1) a single row element $a_{ik} = 1$ and the rest of them are zero, or (2) $a_{ik_1} = 1, a_{ik_2} = -1$, where $k_1<k_2$, and the rest of the row elements are zero.  I am not looking for a least squares solution here, but for a solution in the following sense.
When solving for a single variable $x_i$, I can start removing equations from the system until I arrive at a full rank system that is consistent.  There could be several systems like this, depending on which equations I remove.  For each variable $x$, I would like to come up with a system that gives me the minimal solution for $x_i$ among all such systems (and do that for every variable). Also, I don't need to know which equations such system consists of, as long as I arrive at the minimal solution in the above sense.
This problem reminded me of a Bellman-Ford algorithm (wiki article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), where variables correspond to graph nodes, and the difference equations are path weights or distances.  In fact, after some tests it seems to give me what I want.  It is expensive though, and I am looking for a better way. Thanks.

With your graph model, how do you deal with negative cycles? Are there guaranteed to not occur? If the solution is the shortest path with no repeted vertices, then it is NP-complete.

Can you give the context of the problem ? I have a hunch that your model is not what you expect and what you want is just finding a critical path in a DAG.

@caduk The abstraction I came up with comes from a problem of sourcing a commodity in a certain location.  It can either be sourced locally, or bought elsewhere and delivered for a fee (delivery fee can be negative).  Not all nodes in a distribution network are connected. I'd like to choose the optimal scenario or a route that gives me the lowest price, and repeat this for the rest of the nodes in the network. $x_1-x_2$ represents the cost of delivery.  Thank you for asking the question, it made me question whether the matrix abstraction I was talking about is even correct.

In your description, you indeed seem to be searching for the shortest path from a source to a location. Given you have negative weights, without more assumptions on the nature of your graph, Bellman-Ford is a good choice of algorithm. Note that if you search from the source instead of from the location, with one call of the algorithm, you have the shortest paths from the source to all the nodes in the graph. If your paths are expected to be short, the complexity of the algorithm will be very reasonable, seems you only need as many $\mathcal{O}(E)$ steps as the size of your shortest path.

Thank you, I appreciate the answer
